# как вращать по глобальным осям Ursina Python

Tags: python, координаты, ursina

Вращаю объект с помощью команды 'rotation_z', но при это также воращаются все оси этого объекта. Как предотвратить вращение осей? Есть команда 'world_rotation_z', но не совсем понятно как она работает. Документация умалчивает.

```
from ursina import *
app = Ursina()
cube_1 = Entity(model='cube')
delta=0
def update():
    global delta
    delta = delta + 0.1
    cube_1.rotation_z = delta
app.run()
```

Comment: Вы не можете вращать объект без осей так как вращение объекта и есть вращение его осей. Что вы можете сделать, что поместить объект (и его оси) в другие (объемлющие) оси.

Comment: `rotation_z` и `world_rotation_z`, как я могу догадываться, отличаются порядком в котором применяются повороты. Заметно это будет только если объект уже был повернут ранее.

Comment: Сейчас вы задаёте слишком общий вопрос. Будьте конкретнее: что вы хотите сделать (только не говорите что вы хотите что-то делать с осями, оси пользователю не видны)? Что не получается?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy необходимо одновременно вращать вокруг нескольких осей. Во время вращения вокруг оси 'x' система координат постоянно меняет свое положение, поэтому вращение вокруг другой оси 'z' приводит не к желаемому результату, а к рисованию восьмерок. Оси я построил линиями и вижу как они вращаются.

Comment: Пользуйтесь `world_rotation_...` в этом случае. Или не работает?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy когда вместо 'cube_1.rotation_z = 45' использую 'cube_1.world_rotation_z = 45' вращение не происходит

Comment: Это вообще так не работает. Мне понадобится время чтобы сделать рабочий пример.

Comment: Можно привязать вращение одного предмета к вращению другого с помощью команды 'cube_2.rotation_z=cube_1.world_rotation_z'. При этом cube_2 начнет вращаться вместе с cube_1. Но т.к. оси вращаются вместе с самим объектом, бессмысленную библиотеку Ursina можно удалять. Это тоже самое, что писать в тетради, которую постоянно вращают во всех плоскостях.

Comment: Ursina вполне осмысленная библиотека, не ругайте её. Вы пытаетсь решить сложную задачу недостаточно мощными средствами. Я попытался объяснить в ответе. Это сложно. :(

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите вращать объект вокруг осей `X`, `Y`, `Z` независимо друг от друга. Оси фиксированы в пространстве. Для вращения используем присвоение значений свойствам `rotation_x`, `rotation_y`, `rotation_z`.

Например начнем с нулевых поворотов и повернем сперва по `X`, потом по `Y`:

> ```
> rotation_x = 0  rot X  rotation_x = 90  rot Y   rotation_x = 90 
> rotation_y = 0 ------> rotation_y =  0 ------>  rotation_y = 90 
> rotation_z = 0         rotation_z =  0          rotation_z =  0
> ```

Тоже начальное положение, сперва по `Y`, потом по `X`:

> ```
> rotation_x = 0  rot X  rotation_x =  0  rot Y   rotation_x = 90 
> rotation_y = 0 ------> rotation_y = 90 ------>  rotation_y = 90 
> rotation_z = 0         rotation_z =  0          rotation_z =  0
> ```

В обоих случаях результат одинаков. Действительно, какая разница в каком порядке присваивать значения свойствам объекта.

Но вращения по разным осям в пространстве не могут быть переставлены с сохранением результата. Вращения не коммутируют. В наших двух примерах должны были получится разные результаты.

Противоречие заключается в том что вы не можете вращать объект вокруг разных осей просто присваивая значения каким-то свойствам. Сам способ присваивания порождает схему в которой операции перестановочны, а они не могут быть таковыми.

Ursina в этом не виновата.

Я, наверно, объясняю непонятно. Попытайтесь поиграть с программой ниже. Она реализует нужную вам логику и показывает получившиеся углы. Клавиши `q/a` вращают по `X`, `w/s` по `Y`, `e/d` по `Z`. Чтобы всё работало как ожидается, требуется идти на хитрости с изменением иерархии сцены. Хочу вас успокоить, на такие хитрости идут все кто разрабатывает интерфейсы для поворотов в пространстве в любых трехмерных пакетах.

*NB: Переключение предков в иерархии соответствует операциям на матрицах вращения - обращениям и произведениям матриц. Если вы знакомы с линейной алгеброй и тем как матрицы связаны с поворотами, вы можете по программе выписать матричные операции для поворотов вокруг фиксированных осей. И наоборот, по формулам составить требуемую последовательность операций ("смена папы-поворот-смена папы").*

```
from ursina import *


app = Ursina()

origin = Entity(model='cube', scale=(0.2, 0.2, 0.2))

Entity(model='cube', parent=origin, color=color.red  , position=(5, 0, 0), scale=(10, 0.5, 0.5))
Entity(model='cube', parent=origin, color=color.green, position=(0, 5, 0), scale=(0.5, 10, 0.5))
Entity(model='cube', parent=origin, color=color.blue , position=(0, 0, 5), scale=(0.5, 0.5, 10))

x_handle = Entity()
y_handle = Entity()
z_handle = Entity()


def switch_parent(entity, parent):
    old_world_rotation = entity.world_rotation
    entity.parent = parent
    entity.world_rotation = old_world_rotation


def update():
    old_parent = origin.parent
    switch_parent(origin, x_handle)
    x_handle.rotation_x += held_keys['q'] * 50 * time.dt
    x_handle.rotation_x -= held_keys['a'] * 50 * time.dt

    switch_parent(origin, y_handle)
    y_handle.rotation_y += held_keys['w'] * 50 * time.dt
    y_handle.rotation_y -= held_keys['s'] * 50 * time.dt

    switch_parent(origin, z_handle)
    z_handle.rotation_z += held_keys['e'] * 50 * time.dt
    z_handle.rotation_z -= held_keys['d'] * 50 * time.dt

    switch_parent(origin, old_parent)


app.run()
```